# With haskell's turtle library, how to extract filename as String from FilePath?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

When using takeFileName I get a type error:

```
:t v
print v
:t takeFileName
takeFileName v

v :: FilePath

FilePath "/media/miguel/backup/backups"

takeFileName :: FilePath -> FilePath
Couldn't match type ‘Turtle.FilePath’ with ‘String’
Expected type: IHaskellSysIO.FilePath
  Actual type: Turtle.FilePath
In the first argument of ‘takeFileName’, namely ‘v’
In the expression: takeFileName v
```

Is it because turtle's FilePath is different from prelude's FilePath ?

Comment: I believe you are intended to use `-XOverloadedStrings` with this library.

Comment: Yes, I had OverloadedStrings turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turtle still uses `system-filepath` which has a customized "FilePath" type you can find [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4/docs/Filesystem-Path.html#t:FilePath). Many other Haskell libraries would use a filepath library which just defines `FilePath` as a synonym for a `String` (type FilePath = String). This is the case here with `IHaskell`.

So yes both FilePath types mismatch. Note that you can easily convert `Turtle.FilePath` into a `String` using `show` (because the type has a Show instance). You can also convert it into a `Text` using `fp` from the Turtle.Format module.

`system-filepath` is actually deprecated. There is an issue about this. Please read: https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/issues/54

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, then I was looking for 'filename' from  Filesystem.Path.

Comment: @miguel.negrao Yes ;-)

Comment: It seems that show doesn't convert to String properly it will convert as "FilePath \"path here\"". It seems I need to use instead  Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS.encodeString.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by in the comment by miguel.negrao, you need the `system-filepath` library (deprecated - but I can't find any other solution).

```
import Turtle hiding (f
import Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS (encodeString, fromText)

let f = fromText $ "/test/abc.txt" :: Turtle.FilePath
print $ encodeString f
```

The above will output `/test/abc.txt`.