# Haskell: unsolicited unicode character escaping in i/o

Tags: haskell, unicode

I've got a CLI utility for copying files, basically.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
...
import Turtle
...
{- Command line parser -}
-- | Represents command line options.
data Settings = Settings
  { sVerbose           :: Bool
...
  , sSrc               :: FilePath
  , sDst               :: FilePath
  }
...
```

Tracing code:

```
...
-- | Extracts String From FilePath (unsafe and unofficial).
-- No double quotes allowed in paths.
strp :: FilePath -> String
strp path =
  let parts = splitOn "\"" (show path)
 in  parts !! 1
...
  putStrLn "Наблюдаем юникод"
  putStrLn $ strp (sSrc args)
  putStrLn $ strp src
...
```

Working code:

```
...
src         <- realpath (sSrc args)
...
```

Console input for `sSrc` is actually `.`

Console output:

```
Наблюдаем юникод
./
/home/alexey/common/Downloads/UpDown/Books/Audio/_Nonfiction_/Moral Combat \8211 Good and Evil in World War II [Unabridged]/
 1/26 /home/alexey/dir-dst/Moral Combat \\8211 Good and Evil in World War II [Unabridged]/01-Moral Combat \\8211 Part 01.mp3
```

`\8211` is some kind of dash. The escaped path is produced by `realpath` right out of the `.`. I don't know the reason why. Is it the particular i/o library? Is it compiler options? The only thing so far that wouldn't escape unicode characters is `putStrLn`.

I want the original path intact.

UPD:

[Make it easy to extract a file path as Text from a FilePath](https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/issues/97)

The hack now looks prettier:

```
import qualified Filesystem.Path.CurrentOS as FPS
import Data.Either.Extra
...
-- | Extracts String From FilePath
-- (good until deprecated system-filepath removed).
strp :: FilePath -> String
strp path = T.unpack $ fromRight "" (FPS.toText path)
```

And it works, for the time being. Still, I like the idea of mandatory escaping not at all. `show` and `print` are very helpful generally, and often rendered useless by escaping. No way to turn this off?

Comment: Take a look at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4/docs/Filesystem-Path-Rules.html for less hacky ways to convert between stringy things and paths.

Comment: What is `strp` supposed to do? `show` is definitely the wrong way to implement it.

Comment: `show` was ugly right from the start. I just knew no better. See UPD. I am still very much interested in turning off escaping optionally. `print`, for instance, is often quite useless because of escaping.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov, what exactly do you want in terms of escaping, that `putStrLn` does not satisfy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substring `"\\8211"` is produced by `show` (in `let parts = splitOn "\"" (show path)`), not by `realpath`. Probably you should just delete the call to `show`, though it's not 100% clear what you wanted the tracing code to do.

Comment: Looks like you are right. I use `show` because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659580/with-haskells-turtle-library-how-to-extract-filename-as-string-from-filepath . Unfortunately, it is not just tracing: I have to mangle some file/path names, so I can't dispense with conversion. Do I have to use another i/o library to get rid of escaping?

Comment: Wow, huh, there doesn't seem to be a way to convert a [`FilePath`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4/docs/Filesystem-Path.html) to a string.. at all.  I see why you did that `show` hack.  From a comment on the question you linked, it looks like that system-filepath library is deprecated anyway, and it recommends using ndmitchell's [filepath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath) library instead.  I'm not familiar enough with Turtle to know if it would be compatible.

Comment: AHA!  You *can* convert a `FilePath` to a string, using [`toText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/system-filepath-0.4.13.4/docs/Filesystem-Path-Rules.html#v:toText) (or I guess technically [`unpack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.0.4/docs/Data-Text.html#v:unpack)`. toText`) from the `System.FilePath.Rules` module.  The trick is, you need to use a `Rules` object to specify the platform flavor the string should be in.  (Oh, dfeuer beat me to this realization an hour ago.  But my comment is more singsongy, innit?)

Comment: @luqui, there's also an `IsString` instance.

Comment: I'd still like to know whether it is possible to turn off escaping generally. If the definitive answer is NO, some explanation or a link to authoritative source is welcome.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Perhaps you had better open a fresh question with the details of what you mean by "turn off escaping", especially if other folks' comments here aren't sufficient; they seem like they should be to me, so you need to post some clarifying details about what's wrong with the proposed alternatives to `show`.